# How to extract second values elements only in every keys in an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, ordereddict

SO, i have this code, i want to extract the second values elements only  in every keys in an OrderedDict, i dont want to use for loop,any idea on this ?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

regDict= OrderedDict()
regDict["glenn"] = (100,200)
regDict["elena"] = (10,20)
print("values",list(regDict.values())[0][1])
print("values",list(regDict.values())[1][1])
```

prints:

```
values 200
values 20
```

target output:

```
values 200,20    # or values ( 200,20 )
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. You can do this through *list comprehension*, which would place the desired values into a list.

Comment: done in list comprehension, compre=[val for val in regDict.values()]  returns : compre [(100, 200), (10, 20)], how can i sliced those  2 items in the last element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it without using explicit loops (I'd say that just putting `for` inside a list comprehension syntax still makes use of a for loop), you can use `map` to only get the second value back as a list, then join those values together with `','.join()` for printing out:

```
>>> ','.join(map(lambda x: str(x[1]), regDict.values()))
'200,20'
```

The `map` call uses the lambda function to return the second value (`[1]`) for each original value:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: str(x[1]), regDict.values()))
['200', '20']
```

Calling `','.join()` with this list as an argument gives you a concatenated string back with each value separated by `,`.

Comment: this saves my day !

Answer (score 0):

OK, some tricks here:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
regDict= OrderedDict()
regDict["glenn"] = (100,200)
regDict["elena"] = (10,20)
print("values",list(regDict.values())[0][1])
print("values",list(regDict.values())[1][1])
second_vals = [str(val[1]) for val in regDict.values()] # Creates a list ['200', '20']
second_vals_as_str = ", ".join(second_vals)
print (f'values: {second_vals_as_str}') # Prints <values: 200, 20>
```

You'd need the `[str(val[1]) for val in regDict.values()]` to do list comprehension which only takes the second number (the `[1]`) and converts it to a string (the `str`).

The `", ".join(second_vals)` joins the strings, separated by commas.